# How to read data-attribute property in mat-radio-button?

Tags: angular

I am trying to retrieve the data-attributes for a mat-radio button within a ngFor loop.

So far, I've tried to get it from the event, but it gives an undefined.
Also, tried the elementRef using #radioEle but not able to drill down into the data-attribute programmatically.

It shows up fine in the console when I see the nested element value though. What am I doing wrong?

```html
          <mat-radio-group [formControlName]="resp.questionPartId">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let option of question.questionParts[i].questionChoices; let optIndex = index">

                  <mat-radio-button [value]="option.value"
                    [attr.data-skip]="option.skipId"   #radioEle (change)="skipQuestion($event, messageEl)">
                    {{option.name}}
                  </mat-radio-button>
                </ng-container>
              </mat-radio-group>
```

```
  skipQuestion(event: any, el: any): void {
    console.log('skip question function : ', event);
    console.log('skip question function : ', event, el.source._elementRef.nativeElement.attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the `$event` itself, for some other things, you can just pass the target of it and get the value from `namedNodeMap`

```html
<!-- Pass target instead of the whole event -->
<mat-radio-button [value]="option.value"
  [attr.data-skip]="option.skipId"
  #messageEl
  (change)="skipQuestion($event.target, messageEl)"
>
  {{option.name}}
</mat-radio-button>
```

And then try to process it. You can do it with the element reference also, but this way (the target way) you need only one parameter.

```typescript
skipQuestion(target: any, el: any): void {
  // Target way
  const nodeMapTarget = target.attributes as NamedNodeMap;
  console.log(nodeMap.getNamedItem('data-skip').value);

  // Element way
  const nodeMapElem = target.attributes as NamedNodeMap;
  console.log(nodeMapElem.getNamedItem('data-skip').value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Researching further, it appears mat-radio-button wraps around the radio button and the event.target parameters are all abstracted from the implementation of the radio button. So "change" doesn't work as is but "Click" works and gets the target, but am not able to get value using getNamedItem. It return a null. Looking for a workaround now, will update.